# Создание нового окна после нажатия кнопки в PyQt5

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, сигналы-слоты

Имеются 2 файла: main.py(главное окно) и example.py(график). Как сделать так, чтобы окно с графиком открывалось только после нажатия определённой кнопки главного окна?
Код 2 файлов предоставлен ниже:

main.py:

```
import sys  # sys нужен для передачи argv в QApplication
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
import design  # Это наш конвертированный файл дизайна
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
import pyqtgraph as pg
import os
class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
  def __init__(self):
    # Это здесь нужно для доступа к переменным, методам
    # и т.д. в файле design.py
    super().__init__()
    self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
    self.setupUi(self)  # Это нужно для инициализации нашего дизайна
    save_button = self.pushButton_4
    start_model = self.pushButton_2
    save_button.clicked.connect(self.save_values)

  def save_values(self):
    current_values = {}
    current_values.update({"t_zapolnenya:": self.spinBox.value() * 60})
    current_values.update({"t1": self.spinBox_3.value() * 60 + self.spinBox_4.value()})
    current_values.update({"t2": self.spinBox_5.value() * 60 + self.spinBox_6.value()})
    current_values.update({"t3": self.spinBox_7.value() * 60 + self.spinBox_8.value()})
    current_values.update({"t4": self.spinBox_9.value() * 60 + self.spinBox_10.value()})
    current_values.update({"t5": self.spinBox_15.value() * 60 + self.spinBox_16.value()})
    current_values.update({"t6": self.spinBox_16.value()})
    current_values.update({"t_otgruzki:": self.spinBox_2.value() * 60})
    print(current_values)




def main():
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
   window = App()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp
   window.show()  # Показываем окно
   app.exec_()  # и запускаем приложение


if __name__ == '__main__':  # Если мы запускаем файл напрямую, а не импортируем
   main()  # то запускаем функцию main()
```

example.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, uic
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys  # We need sys so that we can pass argv to QApplication
import os

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
    self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)

    hour = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
    temperature = [30,32,34,32,33,31,29,32,35,45]

    # plot data: x, y values
    self.graphWidget.plot(hour, temperature)


def main():
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
   main = MainWindow()
   main.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

И как можно передать значения для построения графика с main.py в example.py?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При помощи ключевой технологии Qt, а именно сигнально-слотовой коммуникации между объектами.

Вариант для независимых окон приложения.

Добавьте в класс App сигнал:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import pyqtSignal

class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):

   # Сигнал с данными - допустим массив температур
   dataChanged = pyqtSignal([])

   def __init__(self):
       ...
       # Далее на кнопку повесим локальный слот для сбора
       # необходимых данных и отправки их "потребителям" для отрисовки
       start_model.clicked.connect(self._emitData)

   def _emitData(self):
       data = []
       data.append(self.spinBox.value()*60)
       data.append(self.spinBox_2.value()*60)
       # И так далее
       # Эмитируем сигнал с данными
       self.dataChanged.emit(data)

Теперь в классе графика добавим слот для получения данных:

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.graphWidget)

    def drawData(self, temperature=[])
        # Показываем окно, если оно закрыто
        self.show()

        hour = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        # Здесь, при необходимости, можно добавить необходимые проверки

        # plot data: x, y values
        self.graphWidget.plot(hour, temperature)
```

Вернемся в файл main.py:

```
from example import MainWindow

def main():
   app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)  # Новый экземпляр QApplication
   window = App()  # Создаём объект класса ExampleApp   

   graphWindow = MainWindow()
   window.dataChanged.connect(graphWindow.drawData) # Показываем окно и рисуем данные 

   window.show()  # Показываем окно
   app.exec_()  # и запускаем приложение


if __name__ == '__main__':  # Если мы запускаем файл напрямую, а не импортируем
   main()  # то запускаем функцию main()
```

Другой вариант - это вызов окна с графиком из объекта главного окна,
то есть окно с графиком является объектом главного окна приложения:

```
# Импортируем окно для отрисовки графика

    from example import MainWindow

    class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):

       def __init__(self):
           ...
           # Объявим переменную окна с графиком
           self.graphWindow = MainWindow()

           # На кнопку повесим локальный слот для сбора
           # необходимых данных и отправки их "потребителям" для отрисовки
           start_model.clicked.connect(self.showGraphWindow)

       def showGraphWindow(self):
           # Собираем данные в массив
           data = []
           data.append(self.spinBox.value()*60)
           data.append(self.spinBox_2.value()*60)
           # И так далее

           self.graphWindow.drawData(data)
```